# Find the area of the shaded $\triangle MON$ in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In the figure shown, if ABCD is an isosceles trapezoid, calculate the area of the triangular region MON.(Answer: $\frac{3\sqrt{15}}{4}$)

[image]

I have calculation of the base of the triangle. I would need to find the radius of the inscribed circle.

As for the base $MN$ , we find the missing length $x$ through harmonic division since $M, E$ ($MN$ meeting $AD$), $F$($NM$ meeting $CD$) and $N$ form a harmonic quadruple .

So: $$\frac{x}{1}=\frac{(x +4)}{3}$$$$ \implies x=2\\
\therefore MN=6$$

[image: Drawn2Scale]

Comment: Since the figure seems to be drawn to scale, there is no way that $MN=6$. It would mean that $F$ is the middle of $MN$.

Comment: @Andrei  Peruvian exercise figures are usually not to scale.

Comment: We added a drawn-to-scale diagram to show that $MN=6$.

Comment: @YNK Your added diagram --- should the label V really be N?

Comment: There must be some missing info. I solved the problem for a square (which is a particular isosceles trapezoid) and got $18/5$ for the area.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  There are other alternatives: $\sqrt{17} ,2.5, 3.5, \frac{4\sqrt{13}}{3}$

Comment: I see, but I just constructed another solution with GeoGebra and the area is $2.02$. Looks like the answer depends on the shape of the trapezium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be correct with following conditions:

1-ON is perpendicular on CD, Mark it's intersection with CD as H.

2-OE is parallel with CD, so $OE\bot ON$

3-$\frac {OH}{ON}=\frac 14$

4- $OE=DE=1$

5- The intersection of MN and CD, G is midpoint of MN , so $ME=2$

6- points  M, O and C are colinear.

7- The extension of side BA meets extension of NE at M such that $ME=2 EG=2$

In this case we have:

$ON=\sqrt {4^2-1^2}=\sqrt {15}$

$A_{OEN}=\frac 12 ON\times OE=\frac{\sqrt{15}}2$

The altitude of right triangle OEN from O is :

$ OF=OH=\frac {\sqrt{15}}4$

$A_{OEM}=\frac 12 ME \times OF=\frac 12 \times 2\times\frac {\sqrt{15}}4=\frac{\sqrt{15}}4  $

finally :

$A_{MON}= A_{OEN}+A_{OEM}=\frac{\sqrt{15}}2+\frac{\sqrt{15}}4=\frac{3\sqrt {15}}4$

Answer (score 3):

Let $a$ be the radius of the incircle, $2b=AD$ and $2c=BC$. From right triangle $ABO$ we get $c=a^2/b$.

If $x=ED$ then $CN=3x$ and from $BN=3AE$ we get: $x=b-c/3$.
If moreover $\alpha=\angle BAD$, we get:
$$
\cos\alpha={b-c\over b+c}={b^2-a^2\over b^2+a^2}.
$$
We can then apply the cosine rule to triangle $MAE$, and after some simplifications we obtain:
$$
a^2+9b^2=12b.
$$
Any pair of numbers $(a,b)$ satisfying the above equation and with $b\ge a$ gives a valid solution to the problem, leading to an area of $3a$.

Note that $(a,b)$ can be seen as the coordinates of a point on an ellipse and $0<a\le6/5$, $6/5\le b<4/3$. Hence the area can take any value between $0$ and $18/5$.

EDIT.

If $K$ is the intersection between $NO$ and $CD$, $H$ the midpoint of $BC$ and making the additional assumption that $CD\perp ON$, from Pythagoras' theorem applied to triangles $NOH$ and $NCK$ we get:
$$
ON^2=(3x+c)^2+a^2=9b^2+a^2=12b
$$
and
$$
(ON-a)^2=(3x)^2-c^2.
$$

Combining these equations with the relations found above,
one gets $b=5/4$ and $a=\sqrt{15}/4$, whence the solution $3\sqrt{15}/4$ for the area.

Comment: I didn't try but what if $ON$ goes through the tangency point as depicted in the figure?

Comment: @ACB In that case I get about $2.90$ for the area, which is indeed compatible with the given solution. But in the figure $CD$ doesn't look perpendicular to $ON$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I think that then the information about $ON$ being perpendicular to $CD$ was missing for us to have the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  Could you explain your solution with $ CD \perp ON$?

Comment: @petaarantes I added some details.